# How do you set a cookie with one PHP file and read it with another?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have two files placed in my domain medieland.dk/plakat/
these are called designer_kids.php and vejledning.php

I am trying to save some data in a Javascript cookie in designer_kids and read it in vejledning.php

**designer_kids.php:**

```
    <script>
document.cookie = 'sel=color1jpg; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/plakat/; domain=.medieland.dk';
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#right').css("background-image", "url(pictures/color1.jpg)");

          $("#color1").click(function(){
            $('#right').css("background-image", "url(pictures/color1.jpg)");
          });

          $("#color2").click(function(){
            $('#right').css("background-image", "url(pictures/color2.jpg)");
          });

          $("#color3").click(function(){
            $('#right').css("background-image", "url(pictures/color3.jpg)");
          });

});
    </script>
```

**vejledning.php:**

```
<?php 
    echo "her kommer teksten <p> </p>";
    echo $_COOKIE["sel"];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it...

The problem was that the 2 phpfiles was not in the same folder.  I placed them in same folder and removed the path=/plakat/